# KERAS stuck randomly while adding first layer inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, fastapi

I have created a classification model using Python 3.9.5, Keras 2.4.3 and tensorflow-cpu 2.5.0. The model works fine in on my Windows 10 development environment but it stops executing further script and gets stuck when I deploy it in a Docker container. The step where it gets stuck and becomes unresponsive is when I add the first layer. Nothing gets printed in logs either.

This behavior is random (has happened 4th and 20th time and any number of times in between) while training. For reproducible results I train the model in a separate process due to the randomness produced by 3rd party libraries used in my FastAPI application. Also, I do not see anything out of the ordinary when I run docker ps.

#### Source code / logs

**Model Structure**

```
try:
        log.info("Initializing Sequential Model")
        model = Sequential()

        log.info("Initializing GlorotNormal")
        initializer = initializers.GlorotNormal()

        log.info("Adding LSTM as input layer ")
        model.add(LSTM(100,  input_shape=(
            train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=False))

        log.info("Adding hidden dense layer")
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='selu', name="layer2", 
            kernel_initializer=initializer))
        
        log.info("Adding Dropout")
        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))

        log.info("Adding Output layer")
        model.add(Dense(len(intent_tags), activation='softmax', name="layer3"))
        
        log.info("Generating model Summary")
        model.summary()

        log.info("Compiling model")
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=
           tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=0.005), metrics=['accuracy'])

        log.info("Model Compiled succesfully")
```

**Model fit:**

```
model: Sequential = create_training_model(train_x, train_y, intent_tags)
log.info("Model Created")

add_into_queue: LambdaCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch,_: queue.put({"type": "progress", "sub_type": "training_progress", "progress": f'EPOCHS: {epoch+1}/{configuration_epochs}'}))
es: EarlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', mode='min',verbose=1, patience=30, min_delta=1)
log.info("fitting Training")

history: object = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=200, batch_size=5,
                  verbose=1, validation_data=(test_x, test_y), 
                  callbacks=[es, add_into_queue])

 
if es.stopped_epoch:
      training_completed_message: str = f"Training completed {es.stopped_epoch}/{configuration_epochs} Epoch, Early Stopping applied"
      log.info(training_completed_message)

      progress_data: dict = {"type": "progress", "sub_type":"training_completed"  , "progress": str(training_completed_message)}
      queue.put(progress_data)

else:
      progress_data: dict = {type": "progress", "sub_type": "training_completed","progress": str(configuration_epochs)}
      queue.put(progress_data)
```

**Fastapi websocket code snippet for training model:**

```
try:
    configuration["TRAINING_COUNT"] +=1
    log.info(f"Training Count: {configuration['TRAINING_COUNT']}")
    log.info("Starts training on seprate procces")
    multi_process = Process(target=chatbot_training, args=(qestions_answers, training_type, client_id, saved_file_path, queue), name=f"training_process_{client_id}")
    multi_process.start()
                        
   log.info("Initializing thread to send training progress")
   data_progress_thread = threading.Thread(target = send_data_progress_call, args=[websocket, queue] , name="data_progress_thread")
   data_progress_thread.daemon = True
   data_progress_thread.start()
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
python -m nltk.downloader punkt && \
python -m nltk.downloader wordnet && \
python -m nltk.downloader averaged_perceptron_tagger && \
python -m pip cache purge
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=100
CMD ["python", "./starfighter/app.py"]
```

**Docker Container logs**:
[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ifbj.png)

**Result of docker stats container_name:**
[Container stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbXJf.png)

**Results of docker top container_name:**
[top command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiVla.png)

**Logs on development environment**
[Logs on development environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CpRW.png)

#### Steps to reproduce:

train model 20-40 times to reproduce the error, for saving time use small dataset

#### Environment information

```
Server OS = Centos 7
docker base image = python:3.9.5-slim-buster
Python Version = 3.9.5
tensorflow-cpu==2.5.0
keras==2.4.3
nltk==3.5
pyspellchecker==0.6.2
pandas==1.2.4
fastapi==0.65.1
aiofiles==0.7.0
openpyxl==3.0.7
websockets==9.0.2
numpy==1.19.5
strictyaml
uvicorn==0.13.4
PyYAML==5.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using uvicorn, the uvicorn workers get resources from docker and everytime  the model layers are created it gets stored in the memory, and the issue of stucking up is due to the lack of workers resources given to it by the container.
So, you can try another wsgi server or try profiling the workers how much resources it is using up.
I had a similar issue while running inside docker and gunicorn where the models were preloaded so removing the --preload argument did the job.